# Not able to retrieve data from firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection 'posts' which has documents as uid of the particular users, under each document I have array 'posts' which contains a string 'likes' and a map 'post' which again contain a string 'userpost'.

I need to show data of the 'userpost' as a list in my homepage.  Can someone suggest me a   query for this.

I tried this:

`return Firestore.instance.collection('posts').where('posts', arrayContains: 'post').snapshot();`

And in my home page under listview.builder I'm retrieving data like this:-

`Text( snapshot.data.documents[i].data['userpost'], )`

But after running It isn't showing anything in the homepage and an execption is thrown: A build function returned null.

Comment: add await for snapshot,  store it in variable and do console.log first to see whether you are getting data or not.  don't forget to use .val()

Answer (score 1):

Firestore QuerySnapshot which  you have to loop over to get the actual document map

Should try this

```
snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot doc){

if(doc.data.hasdata)){
return Text( doc.data.data['userpost'], );
}
return Text('Loading');
}).toList()
```